Games with uncountable pure strategies
Does it make any sense to consider games where players can choose from an uncountable set of pure strategies? Is there any game-theoretic notion of such a game?
Consider, for example, the situation where two players $X$ and $Y$ each choose a point on the real interval $[0,1]$, say that $X$'s payoff after he chooses $x$ and $Y$ chooses $y$ is $u_X(x,y)$ where $u_X:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is, at first, just a function.
Might this constitute an instance of non-cooperative game? If so, should $u$ be required to be continuous or bilinear over the space of mixed strategies as usual with the standard payoff matrix setting?
In the finite strategy case, mixed strategies a player with $n$ pure strategies are probability distributions over them (i.e. the simplex $\Delta^n$). In this setting, a Nash equilibrium is a pair of (possibly mixed) strategies $(p,q)\in \Delta^n\times\Delta^m$ such that $$u_X(p,q)=\max_{s\in \Delta^n}u_X(s,q) \hspace{2cm}u_Y(p,q)=\max_{t\in \Delta^m}u_Y(p,t).$$
Alternatively, each player is indifferent when playing any pure strategy against the other's (possibly mixed) one: $$\forall x,x' \;\text{pure}\;\; \sum_{y\;\text{pure}} u_X(x,y) q(y)=\sum_{y\;\text{pure}} u_X(x',y) q(y)$$ and the same for player $Y$.
Could we define a mixed strategy in the uncountable case as a probability distribution  over $[0,1]$ so that a (mixed) Nash equilibrium $(p,q)$ satisfies $$\forall x,x'\in[0,1]\;\;\;\int_0^1 u_X(x,y)q(y)dy =\int_0^1 u_X(x',y)q(y)dy\;\;\;?$$
Is this a well posed problem?
Of course, even if all the above was admissible, we would not get mutatis mutandis existence of Nash equilibria since they depend heavily on the convexity and compacity of $\Delta^n$. In my example, the sets of mixed strategies are still convex but most certainly fail to be compact.
Answers to any of my questions above, as well as comments are greatly appreciated.

see this
